# AWS CodePipeline Error "An operation on this ChangeSet is currently in progress. Please attempt this operation again later"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I am getting a very strange error when using AWS CodePipeline. I created my project from CodeStar using the "Nodejs + AWS Lambda + Web service" scaffold.

I'm just trying to run the "Deploy" build step, but it is giving me this error:

> Action execution failed An operation on this ChangeSet is currently in
>   progress. Please attempt this operation again later. (Service:
>   AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   InvalidChangeSetStatus; Request ID:
>   f9e5a5a0-6e86-11e8-8db7-3f04173419bf)

The "change set" name by default is "pipeline-changeset". There is an option to change it when you edit the build step, but strangely even when I change the name it still reverts back to "pipeline-changeset". Is this a bug in AWS CodePipeline? Has anyone else experienced this issue? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the end this turned out to be caused by my own errors in setting up the CodePipeline stages / actions. I had created additional "Deploy" stages for multiple environments, and after I did this I was seeing the error. It seems that all actions / stages / projects can use a *Change set name* that is just named "pipeline-changeset", and there was no issue here in my project (which, I think, is why the error message was so confusing).

The actual issue was that I had multiple Deploy stages all referring to the same ***Stack name***. So, the moral is the story is that if you want to have multiple Deploy stages then they need to all have their own Stack name (and you'll also need to modify your IAM roles accordingly).